# How to delete dynamically created Content Projection Transclusion element in angular2?

Tags: angular, transclusion

I have created two widget components, for example, Data and Chart widget which are transclusion by another component named Card component. In Card component, I have used a common close button so that I can use the close button in every widget by default. The Data and Chart widget created dynamically and save in an array and finally the components are rendered on html template. **Now, I would like to delete the components from the array by clicking the close button on each widgets.** I tried in the following way,

CardComponent.ts

```
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import {WidgetComponent} from './widget.component';

@Component({      
    selector: 'card',
    templateUrl: 'card.component.html',
})
export class CardComponent {

    @Input()
    public header: string = 'this is header';

    @Input()
    public footer: string = 'this is footer';

    @Output() closeWidget = new EventEmitter();

    close(){
      console.log('Card close');
      this.closeWidget.emit();
    }        
}
```

CardComponent.html

```
<div class="card" style="border: 1px solid #d0d0d0;">
  <div class="card-header">        
    {{ header }}      
  <a (click)="close()" class="btn btn-primary">Close</a>
  </div>
  <ng-content></ng-content>
  <div class="card-footer">
    {{ footer }}       
  </div>
</div>
```

chart-widget.component.ts

```
@Component({
selector: 'chart-widget',
templateUrl: './app/chart-widget.component.html',
providers: [{provide: WidgetComponent, useExisting: forwardRef(() => ChartWidget) }]
})

export class ChartWidget extends WidgetComponent implements OnInit {

}
```

chart-widget.component.html

```
<card header="Chart Panel" footer="Footer here" class="ui-toolbar-group-
right">             
    <div class="card-block">
    <h4 class="card-title">Chart Card</h4>
    <p class="card-text">Chart showing here</p>

  </div>
</card>
```

AppComponent.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app/app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app/app.component.css'],
  entryComponents: [ChartWidget,  DataWidget], 
})

export class AppComponent {
   private elements: Array<{ view: ViewRef, component: WidgetComponent}>=[];
   private WidgetClasses = {
      'ChartWidget': ChartWidget,
      'DataWidget': DataWidget        
  }
  @ViewChild(DynamicComponent) dynamicComponent:DynamicComponent;  


  addComponent(widget: string ): void{
    let component = this.dynamicComponent.addComponent(this.WidgetClasses[widget]);
    let view: ViewRef = this.dynamicComponent.container.detach(0);
    this.elements.push({view,component});

    this.dynamicComponent.resetContainer();
  }

  onWidgetDelete(element: any){
        console.log('Call Delete called');
        var index = this.elements.findIndex((elt) => (elt===element));
        if (index !== -1) {
            this.elements.splice(index, 1);
        }


    }
}
```

app.component.html

```
<button (click)="addComponent('ChartWidget')">Add ChartWidget</button>
<button (click)="addComponent('DataWidget')">Add DataWidget</button>

<dynamic-component [hidden]="true" ></dynamic-component>  

<hr>
Dynamic Components
<hr>
<widget *ngFor="let item of elements" (closeWidget)="onWidgetDelete(item)">
  <ng-container *view="item.view" ></ng-container>
</widget>
```

I am getting the click event message on console but the EventEmitter does not work. How do I delete the components by clicking the close button? 
Here is my Plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/tFmcpre6FHysJ1uUFPp5?p=preview

Comment: I think you have over-engineered this solution a tad. Is there any requirement to use transclusion as much as you are using it here? , edit: I would not have used so much classical inheritance either.

Comment: I have some common button functions, in this case I have only mentioned close button but in future it will extend with some other buttons which have common features for every widgets. that's why I have decided to use transclustion. Do you have any other good solution for it?

Comment: My bad - I read this in a hurry this morning. I see your problem now, I'm not sure if there is any easy solution to remove dynamic transcluded content - I'll have a look anyway